# Как отключить Source map в Webpack 4 Production Mode

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Выключить сорс мап в продакшн моде, но оставить его в Dev режиме?
let path = require('path');

```
// Plugins
let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
let ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
let FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');
const owl = require('webpack');

let conf = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
        filename: "js/main.js",
        publicPath: ""
    },


    // Server
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        publicPath: "",
        host: '192.168.0.101',
        port: '8080'
    },

    // Modules
    module: {
        rules: [

            // Js
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },

            // Css
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    // fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },

            // Sass
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    {
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [
                            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                            { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
                        ]
                    })
            },

            // Image
            {
                test: /\.(png|ico|gif|jpe?g)$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '../[path][name].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                    'img-loader',
                ]
            },

            // Svg
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            },

            // Fonts
            {
                test: /\.(otf|eot|ico|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                }]
            },
        ]
    },

    // Config Plugins
    plugins: [

        // Extract Text

        // Pages

            /* Home */
            new ExtractTextPlugin("css/style.css"),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                hash: true,
                template: './src/index.html',
                filename: 'index.html'
            }),

        // Fav
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
            logo: './src/fav/fav.ico', // svg works too!
            mode: 'webapp', // optional can be 'webapp' or 'light' - 'webapp' by default
            devMode: 'webapp', // optional can be 'webapp' or 'light' - 'light' by default
            favicons: {
                appName: 'template',
                appDescription: 'template',
                developerName: 'Name',
                developerURL: null, // prevent retrieving from the nearest package.json
                background: '#ddd',
                theme_color: '#333',
                icons: {
                    coast: false,
                    yandex: false
                }
            }
        }),

        // jQuery
        new owl.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),

        // Copy Webpack
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            [
                // img
                {from: './src/img', to: 'img'},

                // php
                // {from: './src/includes', to: 'includes'},
                // {from: './src/functions', to: 'functions'},
            ],
            {
                ignore: [
                    {
                        glob: 'svg/*'
                    },
                ]
            }
        ),

        // Image min
        new ImageminPlugin({ test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$/i,
            disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production', // Disable during development
            pngquant: {
                quality: '15-100'
            },
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = (env, options) => {
    let production = options.mode === 'production';

    conf.devtool = production
        ? 'source-map'
        : 'eval-sourcemap';

    return conf;
};
```